# Why is angular not rerendering?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I call $scope.remove in the html it calls the rerender function then automatically updates the data in the html.

When I call $scope.post it calls the rerender function and logs the new data. However, it doesn't automatically rerender the html. I have to refresh the page in order to see the up to date data.

I've looked into using $apply but I'm puzzled how it's updating for remove but not post.

**Controller:**

```
var updateData = function (resp){
  $scope.data = resp.data;
  console.log($scope.data);
}

$scope.getEntries = function (){
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/allEntries'
  }).then(updateData)
};

$scope.post = function (){
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/newEntry',
    data: $scope.entry
  }).then(function (resp){
    $scope.getEntries();
  })
};

$scope.remove = function (opp){
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/deleteEntry',
    data: opp
  }).then(function (){
    $scope.getEntries();
  })
}
```

I'm thinking it might be something to do with having the functions called in different html files but since they both have the same controller I would think that wouldn't be the case.

```
<html>
  <body ng-app = "app">
    <div ng-controller = "controller">
    <form ng-submit = "post()">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>`

<html>
  <body ng-app = "app">
    <div ng-controller = "controller">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat = "job in data" ><input type = "button" ng-click = "remove(opp)" value="Delete"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you have two different sections, each with their own controller, and thus each with their own scope:

- one which displays the list of items
- one which diesn't display anything

You're posting from the section which doesn't display anything, so it refreshes the list in the scope of that section, which still doesn't display anything.

So, in short, both sections don't have the same controller. They have different controller instances, and those instances happen to have the same type. But they're still completely independant from each other.

And actually, re-reading your question, it's actually worse than that. It seems you have two browser tabs or frames opened. You are posting from one of the tabs, and hope that the other one will refresh automatically. That won't happen: the two tabs are completely independant applications.